# Tweaking the side menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page http://www.cheilenereinfo.ro/handmade/

I found two scripts and combined the website and the left side menu.
My css knowledge are very…but very low, so, if possible, please help me sove this problem.

I have these two pictures, with the closed and opened menu and some information regarding my needs.

closed menu:

[closed menu http://www.cheilenereinfo.ro/handmade/closed_menu.jpg](http://www.cheilenereinfo.ro/handmade/closed_menu.jpg)

opened menu:

[opened menu http://www.cheilenereinfo.ro/handmade/opened_menu.jpg](http://www.cheilenereinfo.ro/handmade/opened_menu.jpg)

All I need is to have that menu visible. When opened, it appears over the pictures and the menu cannot be seen. What can I do to place the menu in the white space, between the left side of the website and the picture gallery? Waht do I have to change or what code do I need to add? Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you got to far, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a margin to the image grid. The class of the grid is `og-grid`.

```
.og-grid {
margin-left: 10%;
}
```

What class has the line?